# Getting data from xml into leaflet map

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, leaflet

I have a Leaflet map and I want to include some data from a webservice that returns the data in [a strange XML format](http://www.fdsn.org/xml/station/).

- Is leaflet able to handle XML somehow? (I'm afraid it isn't as I didn't find anything about that)
- If not, what would be the best/easiest way to handle that XML? Should I write/use (I found a lot of them) a parser to convert the XML to a more leaflet-comptaible format like (geo)json? Should I parse the XML directly into a Leaflet-Layer (sounds like writing a plugin myself)?
- Is there any other option I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your XML data contains- If it is a lot of geographic information I would consider converting it to [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/).

I'm using something similar where I use a php xml handler to edit an existing KML into a format that is more Leaflet friendly, then loading it into my map with [this](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/blob/master/examples/kml.html).

Otherwise I think geojson is the way to go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, there is a link above describing the XML format  I get. Your link to KML might be useful - I thought KML was just another strange XML format that leaflet can't handle but it seems like it's usable. Would you recommend converting my XML to geojson or to KML? What advantages would the latter have if there is "a lot of geographic information"?

Comment: I think it depends of the use of your data? In my example, I use leaflet to track scientific assets, so I want both the "wow" of having it on a website and also the flexibility to give mid-level users the data to view on something offline like google earth. It's also important to me that I can use most data thrown me way on my maps/display. So I chose the KML route (as it's pretty common). I think if your application is only for yourself, then converting your xml to Geojson is the way to go. But this is as far as my knowledge goes.

Answer (score 0):

The X in XML stands for "extensible".  The link provided above (FDSN) is not a "strange format", but rather it's a particular schema.  JSON is a very easy to use format because no schema information is required, although JSON schemas do exist.  However, when information needs to be standardized, for any number of reasons, a schema is necessary in order for the information to be comprehensible.  The FDSN schema apparently represents the standard metadata schema for working with seismographic data.  One will find that various industries and organizations have decided on elements to be incorporated in documents for purposes of interoperability.

XML generally is not as straight-forward as JSON (or GeoJSON), but the reason it is used is precisely because of the extensibility, because in many applications and data collections a rich metadata schema is required and/or preferrable.  Regardless, a quick conversion may not be possible if the schema itself is not well understood.

See the following link for an outstanding tutorial on using XML in Leaflet.  NOTE: Anytime XML is used, one needs to at least open the file and look around in order to get an understanding of exactly what each element entails.  Where is the coordinate information, if any?

http://erica.altschul.info/Tutorial_XML-to-Leaflet.pdf